# Change the color of the "default" value of an input

Tags: javascript

I have this code ->

```
var searchexampletxt = '<?php echo JText::_('SEARCH_EXAMPLE'); ?>';
Window.onDomReady(function(){

$('BLA_BLA').addEvent('focus',function(){
    if(this.value=='<?php echo JText::_('SEARCH_EXAMPLE');?>')
    {
    this.value="";
        }
    });

$('BLA_BLA').addEvent('blur',function(){
    if(this.value=='')
    {
    this.value="<?php echo JText::_('SEARCH_EXAMPLE');?>";
        }
    }); 

});
```

Can somebody help me please, how can I make the "SEARCH_EXAMPLE" text (that is by default shown in inputbox) be for example color #CCCCCC, but the text that I'm writing in the inputbox be for example #333333 ??

Thank you
Cheers

Comment: HTML5's `placeholder` attribute will happily do this for you, as will any of the dozens of plug-ins that provide it when the browser doesn't, [including mine](http://code.google.com/p/place5/).

Comment: I'm curious: You've flagged your question `jquery`, but `Window.onDomReady` isn't jQuery, nor is `addEvent`...

Comment: Hi. Sorry I don't know so much about this, I thought it's something related to JQuery..

Comment: I would LOVE to use html5's placeholder.. but it works only in webkit (

Comment: @ Vzlotea: Hence my saying *"...as will any of the dozens of plug-ins **that provide it when the browser doesn't**..."* and the link to just such a plug-in.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to check the link. I will try that thank you

Comment: @ Vzlotea: That particular one won't help you if you're not using jQuery. There are other, stand-alone ones out there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.style.color="red"` or using hex-code `this.style.color="#FF0000"`.

So, for your example:

1. After `this.value="";` add `this.style.color="#CCCCCC";`
2. After `this.value="<?php echo JText::_('SEARCH_EXAMPLE');?>"` add `this.style.color="#333333";`

Comment: Thank you very much "B7ackAnge7z", this works great. Thank you for your time and for the willing to help.